# Prove $12^n>7^n+5^n $ for $ n\geq2$ by induction.

Tags: inequality, induction

> Prove the inequality $$12^n>7^n+5^n$$ holds true for $ n\geq2$ by induction.

I'm having difficulties understanding how to prove inequalities by induction.

Comment: Hint: $12^{n+1}=12\times 12^n>12\times(7^n+5^n)=(7+5)(7^n+5^n)$.

Comment: It's the same as proving anything else by induction. Start with the base case then assume it holds for the $k$ and show that implies it holds for $k+1$ by manipulating the expression.

Comment: Test it for base case: put $n= 2$.  Assume it holds for $n$, and given that assumption, prove that it implies that it holds for $n+1$.  The only way to learn induction is to try.  Please improve your work with your attempts, given the tips in these comments.

Answer (score 2):

Recurrence :

$12^n>7^n+5^n$

For $ n=2 $

$12^2>7^2+5^2$

$\Rightarrow $ $ 144>74$ that is true

Suppose :$12^n>7^n+5^n$

For $n+1$

Let's show $12^{n+1}>7^{n+1}+5^{n+1}$

We know:$12^n>7^n+5^n$

$\Rightarrow $ $12^{n+1}>7^n(5+7)+5^n(5+7)$

$\Rightarrow $ $12^{n+1}>7^{n+1}+5× 7^n+5^{n+1}+7×5^n$

$\Rightarrow $ $12^{n+1}>7^{n+1}+5^{n+1}+5 ×7^n+7×5^n>7^{n+1}+5^{n+1}$

So:
$12^{n+1}>7^{n+1}+5^{n+1}$

Finally

$12^n>7^n+5^n$

Comment: Nice proof (+1).

Comment: @Angelo Thank you, but What do you mean ((+1))

Comment: Alright, I think I understand it now, thanks.

Comment: (+1) means that I have upvoted you as your proof is nice.

Comment: @Angelo  OK, thanks

Comment: @GeoCap you're welcome